# What is the difference between the cuda api cu... and cuda...?

Tags: api, cuda

For example [cudaMemcpy](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDA__MEM_g4d32266788c440b0220b1a9ba5795169.html) and [cuMemcpy](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDA__MEM_g8d0ff510f26d4b87bd3a51e731e7f698.html#g8d0ff510f26d4b87bd3a51e731e7f698)? I can see that the function definitions are different, but I mean the API in general. Why is there an api starting with `cu...` and one starting with `cuda...`? When should each API be used?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The API where the method names start with `cu...` is the so called *Driver API*. The API where the method names start with `cuda...` is the *Runtime API*.

Originally (up to CUDA 3.0) the APIs have been completely separated. A rough classification was: The Runtime API is simpler and more conventient. The Driver API is intended for more complex, "low level" programming (and maybe library development).

Since CUDA 3.0, both APIs are interoperable. That means that, for example, when you allocate memory with the Driver API using `cuMemAlloc`, then you can also use the same memory in Runtime API calls, like `cudaMemcpy`.

The major practical difference was that in the Runtime API, you could use the special `kernel<<<...>>>` launching syntax, whereas in the Driver API, you could load your CUDA programs as "modules" (with methods like `cuModuleLoad`), given in form of CUBIN files or PTX files, and launch these kernels programmatically using `cuLaunchKernel`.

In fact, I think that for the largest part of a CUDA program, the differences are negligible: Nearly every other functionality (except for kernel/module handling) is  available in *both* APIs, and nearly equal in both. This refers to methods (`cuMemcpy` and `cudaMemcpy` etc., as well as to structures `CU_event` and `cudaEvent` etc.).

Further information can be found with websearches involving the keywords "CUDA Runtime Driver API", for example, at https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/522598/what-is-the-difference-between-runtime-and-driver-api-/